# ¿Se puede usar el puerto 23 para FTP?

Tags: ftp

Sé que para *FTP* los puertos a usar son el **20** y **21**, pero me gustaría saber si se puede usar el 23. 
Tengo un pequeño código en java para subir archivos por FTP, que funciona bien. pero al poner el puerto **23**, la conexión no da y me preguntaba si era posible por dicho puerto.

Comment: Duda: probaste usarlo antes de preguntar? Tuviste Algún error?

Comment: Deberías agregar eso más el error a tu pregunta

Answer (score 1):

Sí, se puede usar puerto 23 (o cualquier puerto que quiere), con tal que no haya ningún servicio (telnetd en el case de puerto 23) que ya lo usa.  Tiene que configurar el servidor FTP para usar lo por supuesto, y como lo hace depiende en el software.

Comment: Aunque no esté en uso directo, ¿tendría que cambiar el puerto de telnet de igual manera para que funcione?

Comment: Considera mejorar tu aporte con un ejemplo de configuración